# How to save list values separately?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I separate the year, month and day from "today" and have them save under ex. year = , month = , day = , ?

```
import datetime
import time

#veriables

today = datetime.datetime.today()
print("Vpišite datum rojstva v zaporedju l-m-d")
leto = int(input("Leto: "))
mesec = int(input("Mesec: "))
dan = int(input("Dan: "))
 
list2 = [today]
one = list2[1]
two = list2[2]
three = list2[3]
print(list2, one, two, three)
```

I tired following this : [How can I store each value from a list to multiple variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71916902/how-can-i-store-each-value-from-a-list-to-multiple-variables)

Comment: I'm not sure what `list`s have to do with this other than the fact that you're wrapping `today` in one with `list2 = [today]`. However, that's just a single element `list`.. You can get the _attributes_ of `today` with `year = today.year`, etc.

Comment: Note that the OP of the question in your link wrongly rejected the right answer and accepted the one that doesn't answer his question...

Answer (score 1):

```
In [132]: today = dt.datetime.today()

In [133]: today
Out[133]: datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 25, 13, 39, 9, 875333)

In [134]: print("month =", today.month)
month = 4

In [135]: print("date =", today.day)
date = 25

In [136]: print("year =", today.year)
year = 2023
```